# KineticJS moving or removing a circle in a layer

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I hope somone wil help me with this.

I'm new to JS so I still lack a lot of understanding. But the problem with this simple code is, that I want only one circle to be visible in the layer.

How can I move the circle according to the coordinates I get from the list?

```
   <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    $(document).one('mobileinit', function () {

        // Setting #container div as a jqm pageContainer
        $.mobile.pageContainer = $('#container');

        // Setting default page transition to slide
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'slide';

        $('#data-role ul').on('click', function () {
            alert($(this).html());
        });
    });

</script>

<script  type="text/javascript" >
    function placering(x, y) {
        alert(x + " UPS  " + y);
    }
</script>
```

Select something
         
            
                A
                B           
                C

```
<script>

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'topContainer',
        width: 320,
        height: 800
    });

    var layerPlacering = new Kinetic.Layer();


    function spotOn(x1, y1) {
        var moedeSted = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: x1,
            y: y1,
            radius: 10,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 0
        });

        layerPlacering.add(moedeSted);
        stage.add(layerPlacering);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#liste').on('click', 'li', function () {
        layerPlacering.clear();
        var test1 = $(this).attr('val1');
        var test2 = $(this).attr('val2');

        spotOn(test1, test2)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'topContainer',
        width: 320,
        height: 800
    });

    var layerPlacering = new Kinetic.Layer();

    // remove the function    
    var moedeSted = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            radius: 10,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 0
        });
        moedeSted.hide(); // just hide it to start with since you do not know the position where to show    
        layerPlacering.add(moedeSted);
        stage.add(layerPlacering);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#liste').on('click', 'li', function () {
        layerPlacering.clear();
        var test1 = $(this).attr('val1');
        var test2 = $(this).attr('val2');

        moedeSted.setPosition(test1, test2); // <---- Change here
        moedeSted.show(); // if this is the first call, it will make the hidden ring visible, no change otherwise
        layerPlacering.draw();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wonderfull - thanks a lot Ani. I wont tell you, how much time I've spent on this problem, it would be too embarrassing ;)

Comment: Its never embarrassing being a noob. Don't forget to accept & upvote the answers & questions on SO that helped you to solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks again. I've accepted, however, it looks like I cannot vote up because I'm new in this site (active, that is. I've used SO many times to find solutions to my problems). Please correct me if I'm wrong about upvoting.

Comment: Thanks & Yes, there indeed is a restriction for new user. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Helped you with some points with an upVote to move over the beginner threshold :)

Comment: Ahh - nice of you. Actually, I'm impressed it's possible to keep such a high standard on this site. So far, I haven't seen any of the usual ludicrous stuff that's seen in many sites :)